# Ionic app doesn't hit on server when using cordova

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

My Ionic app works fine when running with *ionic serve* but when i use the command *ionic cordova run android --livereload*  it doesn't hit on sever and gives error 
"Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED "
below  is the ionic info

```
   Ionic CLI                     : 4.12.0
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.4.2
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.9
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.3.9
   @angular/cli                  : 7.3.9
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.5.1
```

Cordova:

```
   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.0.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.1, (and 4 other plugins)
```

Utility:

```
   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : 0.2.7
```

System:

```
   NodeJS : v10.16.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.9.2
   OS     : Windows 10
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.ionic.starter" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>MyApp</name>
    <description>An awesome Ionic/Cordova app.</description>
    <author email="hi@ionicframework.com" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Ionic Framework Team</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.3" />

    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.4.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="5.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^4.0.0" /> //latest version
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.0.5" />
</widget>
```

below  is the snapshot that i get when deployed in mobile
[image]

And this is the error i get
[image]

Comment: Already answered here [Same as this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56816916/livereload-doesnt-give-choice-of-addresses)

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: Can you try to remove your plugin cordova plugin ionic webview and run to see if  it work ?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.. multiple times   removed cordova-plugin-ionic-webview plugin even tried by downgrading the version

Comment: check of you have Network Permissions: 
add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in you `AndroidManifest.xml` file

Comment: It already have the permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something to proxy the localhost:8080 requests from the android device back to your dev box where the livereload server is running.

You can do this through port forwarding via the chrome browser by opening `chrome://inspect/#devices` on your dev box, or else configure port forwarding directly on the phone's connection properties itself. I use this to watch traffic via Fiddler on windows dev boxes.

Also, ionic livereload server can be configured to route non-ionic traffic by configuring [service proxies](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/cli/configuring.html#service-proxies).

Answer (score 3):

One option in this scenario is to not pass the -l/-livereload which is for livereload functionality. So just run:

```
ionic cordova run android
```

This will then compile the apk and deploy it to your phone, but won't run a web server to watch for changes.

You can still debug with Chrome in this scenario, but if you make a change to the markup and press save it won't automatically reload the app with that change. You would need to run `ionic cordova run android` again to rebuild and deploy it to your phone.

On the plus side 1: after the first deploy, subsequent builds are much faster, as a gradle server is started.

On the plus side 2: if you disconnect your USB then you can still use your app. With a livereload deployed app it breaks once you disconnect.

I would actually really like to solve your problem as well. As I move around coworking spaces sometimes it seems that the network is locked down somehow and just is blocking certain ports. I haven't figured out exactly why or if there is a workaround for this.

Comment: still i have " Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED " error..Running in the localhost. can u suggest any other possible solution

Comment: i have added the config file also.

Answer (score 0):

A temporary fix is to set base href="."  in index.html .
But your icons will not be loaded.

Permanent Fix:

```
ionic cordova platform remove android
ionic cordova platform add android@7.1.0
ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview@latest
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer but din't work for me.. I get net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error only when i call the server API