# livereload doesn't give choice of addresses

Tags: ionic-framework

After the updation of node.js i found this issue.. when i  run ionic cordova  run android --livereload it is running in localhost

How do i solve this issue ?? please help me..

**Ionic Info:**

```
   Ionic CLI                     : 5.2.1
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.6.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.9
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.3.9
   @angular/cli                  : 7.3.9
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.5.1
```

**Cordova:**

```
   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.0.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.1, (and 4 other plugins)
```

**Utility:**

```
   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : 0.2.7
```

**System:**

```
   NodeJS : v10.16.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.9.2
   OS     : Windows 10
```

Answer (score 1):

So this is a new change in Ionic-cli v5.2.1

You can use this command

**ionic serve --address=0.0.0.0**

or in your case

**ionic cordova run android --livereload --address=0.0.0.0**

or if you have a specific url

**ionic cordova run android --livereload-url=http://localhost:8100**

This will spin up the server like it used to previously, both on the localhost as well as the external url.

See this update documentation for more info 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/cordova-run

Comment: Thanks for answering but I still have the same issue.. Because of this problem my ionic app  doesn't hit on server . It gives net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error